# Oauth2 / Password flow / check permission for a specific entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

The main data information and information in my API is linked to a project(Entity),
What is good approach for password flow: to manage specific permission linked to a project with spring security and OAuth2?

In this application you have **5 micro service**:

- UAA microservice : the authorization server
- Catalog microservice
- Order microservice
- Invoice microservice
- Customer microservice

**Zoom  permission :**

[image: UUAMICROSERVICE]

Each user can have many project, and can have the permission for each project:

- CAN_MANAGE_CATALOG
- CAN_VIEW_CATALOG
- CAN_MANAGE_ORDER
- CAN_VIEW_ORDER
- CAN_MANAGE_INVOICE
- CAN_VIEW_INVOICE
- ...

I have many idea but i am not sure if i have the good approach :

USE CASE : I want to securise the endpoint :

```
http://catalog-service/{project_key}/catalogs
```

Only USER who have permission VIEW_CATALOG OR MANAGE_CATALOG for the project {project_key} can list all catalog present in the project

**My first idea : USE ProjectAccessExpression with preauthorize**

*CatalogController.java*

```
@Controller
public class CatalogController {
     @PreAuthorize("@projectAccessExpression.hasPermission(#projectKey, 'manageCatalog', principal)" +
        " or @projectAccessExpression.hasPermission(#projectKey,  'viewCatalog', principal)")
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/{projectKey}/catalogs",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public @ResponseBody List<Catalog> findByProject(@PathVariable("projectKey") String projectKey) {
        return catalogService.find();
    }
}
```

*ProjectAccessExpression.java*

```
@Component
public class ProjectAccessExpression {

        private RestTemplate restTemplate;
        public boolean havePermission(String projectKey, String permission , String username) {
            Boolean havePermission = restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://uaa-service/permission/check?project=%1&permission=%2&username=%3",
                    projectKey, permission, username
                    ), Boolean.class);
            return havePermission;
        }
}
```

The inconvenient : is need to call UAA Service for each time

**Second idea : USE USER_ROLE**

With user_role

- username | role
- mylogin1 | **SHOP1**.CAN_MANAGE_CATALOG
- mylogin1 | **SHOP1**.CAN_VIEW_CATALOG
- mylogin1 | **SHOP2**.CAN_MANAGE_CATALOG
- mylogin1 | **SHOP2**.CAN_VIEW_CATALOG
- mylogin1 | **SHOP2**.CAN_MANAGE_ORDER
- mylogin1 | **SHOP2**.CAN_VIEW_ORDER
- ...

**SHOP1** is **SHOP2** is projectKey

The inconvenient : i am not sure but if user change permission, i need to revoke all token associate

**Third idea : add specific permission in authentication blob**

I don't know how to do for storing...

And in controller a annotation :

```
@PreAuthorize("@ProjectAccessExpression.hasPermission(authentication, 'manageCatalog||viewCatalog', #projectKey)
```

The inconvenient : same inconvenient at second idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution i use and work fine

** 1 - Load Business Logic Security when user sign **

This example find user with role persist in database, and add all role depending project. After the operation i have authentication token with
GrantedAuthority : ROLE_USER, ROLE_MANAGE_CATALOG:project1, ROLE_VIEW_PROFILE:project1, ROLE_MANAGE_PROJECT:project2, ...

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userService.findByLogin(username);

        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            Object args[] = {username};
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            messageSource.getMessage("user.notexist", args, "User {0} doesn't not exist", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
            );
        }
        if (!user.get().isActivated()) {
            //throw new UserNotActivatedException(String.format("User %s was not activated!", username));
            Object args[] = {username};
            throw new UserNotActivatedException(
                    messageSource.getMessage("user.notactivated", args, "User {0} was not activated", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
        }
        //Here implement your proper logic
        //Add busness logic security Roles
        // eg ROLE_MANAGE_PROJECT:{project_key}, ROLE_MANAGE_CATALOG:{project_key}
        List<Role> bRoles = projectService.getRolesForUser(username)
        user.get().getRoles().addAll(
            bRoles
            );

        UserRepositoryUserDetails userDetails = new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user.get());
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

** 2 check security with preauthorize expression **

In this example only user who have this permission can do this operation:

1. ROLE_ADMIN OR
2. ROLE_MANAGE_PROJECT:{projectKey}

   @PreAuthorize("@oauthUserAccess.hasPermission(authentication, '"+Constants.PP_MANAGE_PROJECT+"', #projectKey)")
       @RequestMapping(
               value="/projects/{projectKey}",
               method = RequestMethod.PUT,
               produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
               )
   public ResponseEntity updateProject(@PathVariable("projectKey") String projectKey,@Valid @RequestBody Project project)

The OauthUserAccess class :

```
@Component("oauthUserAccess")
public class OauthUserAccess {

    /**
     * Check if it is the administrator of the application IMASTER
     * @param authentication
     * @param projectKey
     * @return
     */
    public boolean hasAdminPermission(OAuth2Authentication authentication, String projectKey) {
        if(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities().contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) return true;
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param authentication
     * @param permissionType
     * @param projectKey
     * @return
     */
    public boolean hasPermission(OAuth2Authentication authentication, String permissionType, String projectKey) {
        if (!ProjectPermissionType.exist(permissionType) ||
                projectKey.isEmpty() ||
                !projectKey.matches(Constants.PROJECT_REGEX))
            return false;
        if (authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            //TODO check scope permission
            if(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getScope().contains(permissionType+":"+projectKey)) return true;
        }
        if (hasAdminPermission(authentication, projectKey)) return true;
        String projectPermission = "ROLE_" + permissionType + ":" + projectKey;
        String projectPermissionManage = "ROLE_" + permissionType.replace("VIEW", "MANAGE") + ":" + projectKey;
        String manageProject = "ROLE_" + Constants.PP_MANAGE_PROJECT + ":" + projectKey;
        Predicate<GrantedAuthority> p = r -> r.getAuthority().equals(projectPermission) || r.getAuthority().equals(projectPermissionManage) || r.getAuthority().equals(manageProject);

        if (authentication.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(p)) {
            return true;
        };
       return false;
    }

}
```

3 - Advantage / disadvantage

**Advantage**

the business logic permission is loaded only when user login to the application and not every times so it is powerfull solution for microservice architecture.

**Disadvantage**

Need to update authentication token or revoke the token when permission change else
when you update the permission for user, the user required to logout and login. But you have same issue without this security logic, for example when user is disabled or enable.

My solution i use for example in a controller :

```
newAuthorities = projectService.getRolesForUser(username);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), newAuthorities);
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> accessTokens = tokenStore.findTokensByUserName(principal.getName());
        OAuth2Authentication auth2 = new OAuth2Authentication(authentication.getOAuth2Request(), newAuth);

        accessTokens.forEach(token -> {
            if (!token.isExpired()) {
                tokenStore.storeAccessToken(token, auth2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically looks like your just trying to leverage roles with OAuth 2.0 for your project.  Here is an excerpt of some spring documentation on OAuth 2.0

**Mapping User Roles to Scopes:** http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

It is sometimes useful to limit the scope of tokens not only by the scopes assigned to the client, but also according to the user's own permissions. If you use a *DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory* in your *AuthorizationEndpoint* you can set a flag *checkUserScopes=true* to restrict permitted scopes to only those that match the user's roles. You can also inject an *OAuth2RequestFactory* into the *TokenEndpoint* but that only works (i.e. with password grants) if you also install a *TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter* - you just need to add that filter after the HTTP *BasicAuthenticationFilter*. Of course, you can also implement your own rules for mapping scopes to roles and install your own version of the *OAuth2RequestFactory*. The *AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer* allows you to inject a custom *OAuth2RequestFactory* so you can use that feature to set up a factory if you use *@EnableAuthorizationServer*.

All this basically boils down to is that you can protect your endpoints with different scopes by mapping scopes to your own custom roles.  This will allow you to get really fine grained with your security.

I found a pretty good walk-through you can use as a reference: (Obviously you'll have to configure the settings to your own use case)

https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/

Comment: Hi Matthew, first of all thank for your answer but i don't know how your link  or chapter  can help to know the approach or resolve this question"Mapping User Roles to Scopes" https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/. Have you any use case?

Comment: The real trick here is you would like fine grained security over different areas of your application.  So you can setup custom scopes for each application area then then map different user roles to different scopes.  This will give you very fine grained control as you can setup basically infinite combinations of levels and apply them to different application areas.  "implement your own rules for mapping scopes to roles"

Comment: Ok Matthew, i think is just a basic scheme and this example not show how to define dynamically a specific authorisation according my problematic. Example ROLE_MANAGEPRODUCT_{PROJECTKEY} , project key is create after by user.

Comment: Based on the documentation you are going to need to provide your own custom OAuth2RequestFactory since this will let you setup a custom mapping.  The other option would be to setup a custom token granter if you think that could get you granular enough.